# Aligning pictures using CSS

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to make 3 different icons in a webpage align with some text at the bottom, it's a simple webpage for a school assesment but I am stuck at this part:

[[image: Error]]

So I want to put that pencil in the center top and then another icon at the top right side, but I am struggling as it goes to the bottom and doesn't go up. Here's my code:

HTML:

```
    <div class="aboutContent">

        <div class="aboutspeed">
            <img src="img/speed.png" class="speed">
            <p class="pspeed">Ferrari's 458 Spider official 0-100 km/h (62 mph) acceleration is 2.9-3.0 seconds, while top speed is 325 km/h (202 mph). It has fuel consumption in combined cycle (ECE+EUDC) of 13.3 L/100 km (21.2 mpg-imp; 17.7 mpg-US) while producing 307g/km of CO2.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="aboutdesign">
            <img src="img/design.png" class="design">
            <p class="pdesign">Bla bla bla bla bla bla</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.speed {
    width: 52px;
    height: 55px;
    padding: 15px 0px 10px 190px;;
    display: inline;
}

.pspeed {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 30px;
    width: 28%;
    text-align: justify;
    margin: 0;
}

.design {
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 500px;
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    display: inline;

}

.pdesign {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 400px;
    width: 28%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Thank for helping guys!

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dfg4qLfe/

https://jsfiddle.net/dfg4qLfe/embedded/result/

Comment: please load your images to web, we can't see your images!

Comment: Please post JSFiddle with working images. :)

Comment: fiddle posted! check it out and thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

Avoid defining different `css` classes for a very same properties, for example, if you do have certain class for your `p` tag in your first div, you don't need to define another css class for the second `p` tag that you have in your next div (if you want both to resemble to each other).

I've manipulated your code, made it cleaner, the **CSS Trick** in order to have contents aligned in center is this:

```
.design {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

Checkout the code in here:

[Centered](http://jsfiddle.net/eLvoe3cu/1/)

Comment: that worked, however, it leaves the image at the bottom right on top of the footer instead of on top! Thanks for helping :)

Comment: update your fiddle, by uploading your images, so I can align that for you; whenever you feel like I've solved your issues, please mark it as answered :)

Comment: this is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dfg4qLfe/ and the full screen bit of it https://jsfiddle.net/dfg4qLfe/embedded/result/ , it looks better on my computer hahah thanks man!

Comment: okay, you haven't applied my css codes to this, follow these steps, first create a container div, and inside that container div create a row div, inside that row div, define your columns, this is a bootstrap way so each row can contain 12 columns. In your case, we are gonna need 3 columns within our row div, so you can use col-md-4 class, for each column div you're gonna have. After doing all these, include your img, and p tags with corresponding css attributes I've just linked for you above. This link helps you understand bootstrap grid system better: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 0):

> I want to put that pencil in the center top and then another icon at
>   the top right side, but I am struggling as it goes to the bottom and
>   doesn't go up.

Remove float and modify display property, so image can be displayed in separate line:

```
.design {
     float: none;
     display: block;
}
```

Anyway posting JSFiddle would me show you how to do this, consider it next time.

FYI, Twitter-Bootstrap framework and its grid layout would help you a lot, google it.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I will have a look at the bootstrap. As my subject now is an introduction to web they don't teach much, we don't even talk about bootstrap but I will sure look into it thanks for recommending it :)